# Changing states using setTimeout continuously in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I'm trying to change the states in a loop using setTimeout method. I have declared a default state in my constructor like this

```
constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {

            postType:'star_rating'

        }

    }
```

I want to change the state in 5 seconds which i was able to achieve like this

```
setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                postType: 'image_poll'
            });
        }, 5000);
```

The problem is after another 5 seconds it should change it to another state. And after another 5 seconds the state change should be repeated from the beginning.
So in conclusion the state should change like this

A -> B -> C -> A -> B -> C -> A -> B -> C ....... continuously this should happen. How can i do this?

Comment: Use an array and a counter? Reset counter when > 2?

Comment: If you need to repeatedly perform an action then consider setInterval https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval. You can read the current state to decide what to transition to on each interval.

Comment: @mplungjan could you please show me how?

Comment: `const states = ['image_poll','star_rating','whatever'];
this.currentState = 0; setInterval(() => { this.setState({ if (this.currentState>2) { this.currentState=0; } this.setState({
                postType: states[currentState]
            }) },5000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a simple state machine. This is one possible implementation:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState(getNextState());
}, 5000);
```

and

```
getNextState() {
  if (this.state.postType === 'star_rating') 
    return { postType: 'image_poll' };
  if (this.state.postType === 'image_poll')
    return { postType: 'third_state' };
  return { postType: 'star_rating' };
}
```